# How can I install Skype in Fedora 14 64 bits?

Tags: fedora, software-installation, 64bit, skype

I would like to install Skype in Fedora 14 64 bits. However, I encounter this error during the install:

```
$ yum install skype-4.1.0.20-fedora.i586.rpm
[...]
skype-4.1.0.20-fc16.i586 requires libXss.so.1
skype-4.1.0.20-fc16.i586 requires libQtXml.so.4
skype-4.1.0.20-fc16.i586 requires libQtNetwork.so.4
skype-4.1.0.20-fc16.i586 requires libQtDBus.so.4
skype-4.1.0.20-fc16.i586 requires libQtWebKit.so.4
skype-4.1.0.20-fc16.i586 requires libQtGui.so.4
skype-4.1.0.20-fc16.i586 requires libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)
skype-4.1.0.20-fc16.i586 requires libQtCore.so.4
skype-4.1.0.20-fc16.i586 requires libXv.so.1
skype-4.1.0.20-fc16.i586 requires qtwebkit
[...]
```

If I try the Dynamic version, I encounter this error:

```
$ ~/bin/skype-4.1.0.20/skype 
error while loading shared libraries: libXv.so.1: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Is it possible to install these dependencies? If so, how?

Comment: Is that the 32-bit version of skype? There is a 64-bit version, at least for Debian.

Comment: I cannot find a 64-bit version for Fedora.

Comment: It looks as if you must build one yourself, or just take the debian version.

Answer (score 1):

For the latter case try `yum install libXv`

Comment: > Nothing to do

Comment: How about `yum install libXv.i686` ?